# Error starting Hazelcast in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, hazelcast

I am trying to start Hazelcast in a Kubernetes/Docker cluster.
After some digging on the web, I found that someone has already thought about this.

Currently I am trying to use kubernetes-hazelcast lib

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast-kubernetes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Here is my hazelcast config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.9.xsd" 
           xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <group>
        <name>GROUP_NAME</name>
        <password>GROUP_NAME_PASSWORD</password>
    </group> 
    <network>
        <port auto-increment="true">5701</port>
        <join>
            <multicast enabled="false">
                <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
                <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
            </multicast>
<!--            <tcp-ip enabled="false">
                <interface>127.0.0.1</interface>
            </tcp-ip>-->
            <!-- activate the Kubernetes plugin -->
            <discovery-strategies>
                <discovery-strategy enabled="true" class="com.hazelcast.kubernetes.HazelcastKubernetesDiscoveryStrategy">
                    <properties>
                        <!-- configure discovery service API lookup -->
                        <property name="service-name">service-name</property>
                        <property name="service-label-name">label-name</property>
                        <property name="service-label-value">true</property>
                        <property name="namespace">default</property>
                    </properties>
                </discovery-strategy>
            </discovery-strategies>
        </join>       
        <interfaces enabled="false">
            <interface>10.10.1.*</interface>
        </interfaces>
<!--        <symmetric-encryption enabled="true">

               encryption algorithm such as
               DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding,
               PBEWithMD5AndDES,
               AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding,
               Blowfish,
               DESede

            <algorithm>PBEWithMD5AndDES</algorithm>
             salt value to use when generating the secret key 
            <salt>4oItUqH</salt>
             pass phrase to use when generating the secret key 
            <password>gctuSBc5bKZrSwXk+</password>
             iteration count to use when generating the secret key 
            <iteration-count>19</iteration-count>
        </symmetric-encryption>               -->
    </network>
    <executor-service>
        <pool-size>16</pool-size>
<!--        <max-pool-size>64</max-pool-size>-->
         <queue-capacity>64</queue-capacity>
         <statistics-enabled>true</statistics-enabled>
<!--        <keep-alive-seconds>60</keep-alive-seconds>-->
    </executor-service>
    <queue name="default">
        <!--
            Maximum size of the queue. When a JVM's local queue size reaches the maximum,
            all put/offer operations will get blocked until the queue size
            of the JVM goes down below the maximum.
            Any integer between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE. 0 means
            Integer.MAX_VALUE. Default is 0.
        -->
        <max-size>0</max-size>
        <!--
            Maximum number of seconds for each item to stay in the queue. Items that are
            not consumed in <time-to-live-seconds> will automatically
            get evicted from the queue.
            Any integer between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE. 0 means
            infinite. Default is 0.
        -->
<!--        <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>-->
    </queue>
    <map name="default">
        <!--
            Number of backups. If 1 is set as the backup-count for example,
            then all entries of the map will be copied to another JVM for
            fail-safety. Valid numbers are 0 (no backup), 1, 2, 3.
        -->
        <backup-count>4</backup-count>
        <!--
            Valid values are:
            NONE (no eviction),
            LRU (Least Recently Used),
            LFU (Least Frequently Used).
            NONE is the default.
        -->
        <eviction-policy>NONE</eviction-policy>
        <!--
            Maximum size of the map. When max size is reached,
            map is evicted based on the policy defined.
            Any integer between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE. 0 means
            Integer.MAX_VALUE. Default is 0.
        -->
        <max-size>0</max-size>
        <!--
            When max. size is reached, specified percentage of
            the map will be evicted. Any integer between 0 and 100.
            If 25 is set for example, 25% of the entries will
            get evicted.
        -->
        <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
        <!--
            While recovering from split-brain (network partitioning),
            map entries in the small cluster will merge into the bigger cluster
            based on the policy set here. When an entry merge into the
            cluster, there might an existing entry with the same key already.
            Values of these entries might be different for that same key.
            Which value should be set for the key? Conflict is resolved by
            the policy set here. Default policy is hz.ADD_NEW_ENTRY

            There are built-in merge policies such as
            hz.NO_MERGE      ; no entry will merge.
            hz.ADD_NEW_ENTRY ; entry will be added if the merging entry's key
                               doesn't exist in the cluster.
            hz.HIGHER_HITS   ; entry with the higher hits wins.
            hz.LATEST_UPDATE ; entry with the latest update wins.
        -->
        <merge-policy>hz.ADD_NEW_ENTRY</merge-policy>
    </map>
    <!-- Add your own map merge policy implementations here:     
        <merge-policies><map-merge-policy name="MY_MERGE_POLICY"><class-name>com.acme.MyOwnMergePolicy</class-name></map-merge-policy></merge-policies>
    -->
</hazelcast>
```

After trying to start the program the hazelcast isn´t starting and it is raising an exception

```
2017-10-25 15:44:34,849  INFO [main] DiscoveryService:65 - [192.168.1.83]:5701 [dev] [3.9] Kubernetes Discovery: Bearer Token { null }
2017-10-25 15:44:34,888 ERROR [main] Launcher:97 - Unable to start EventEngineManager
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to configure discovery strategies
        at com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.impl.DefaultDiscoveryService.loadDiscoveryStrategies(DefaultDiscoveryService.java:153)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.impl.DefaultDiscoveryService.<init>(DefaultDiscoveryService.java:60)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.impl.DefaultDiscoveryServiceProvider.newDiscoveryService(DefaultDiscoveryServiceProvider.java:29)
        at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.createDiscoveryService(Node.java:265)
        at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.<init>(Node.java:220)
        at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.createNode(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:160)
        at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:128)
        at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:195)
        at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:174)
        at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:124)
        at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:58)
        at com.nsn.monitor.eva.eem.engine.state.EventEngineManagerContext.startup(EventEngineManagerContext.java:131)
        at com.nsn.monitor.eva.eem.EventEngineManager.init(EventEngineManager.java:59)
        at com.nsn.monitor.eva.eem.Launcher.initialize(Launcher.java:74)
        at com.nsn.monitor.eva.eem.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:57)
Caused by: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: An error has occurred.
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:53)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.createHttpClient(HttpClientUtils.java:144)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.BaseClient.<init>(BaseClient.java:41)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.DefaultKubernetesClient.<init>(DefaultKubernetesClient.java:90)
        at com.hazelcast.kubernetes.ServiceEndpointResolver.buildKubernetesClient(ServiceEndpointResolver.java:74)
        at com.hazelcast.kubernetes.ServiceEndpointResolver.<init>(ServiceEndpointResolver.java:64)
        at com.hazelcast.kubernetes.HazelcastKubernetesDiscoveryStrategy.<init>(HazelcastKubernetesDiscoveryStrategy.java:75)
        at com.hazelcast.kubernetes.HazelcastKubernetesDiscoveryStrategyFactory.newDiscoveryStrategy(HazelcastKubernetesDiscoveryStrategyFactory.java:56)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.impl.DefaultDiscoveryService.buildDiscoveryStrategy(DefaultDiscoveryService.java:185)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.discovery.impl.DefaultDiscoveryService.loadDiscoveryStrategies(DefaultDiscoveryService.java:145)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: no more data allowed for version 1 certificate
        at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.parse(X509CertInfo.java:672)
        at sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo.<init>(X509CertInfo.java:167)
        at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.parse(X509CertImpl.java:1804)
        at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:195)
        at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:102)
        at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:339)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.internal.CertUtils.createTrustStore(CertUtils.java:68)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.internal.CertUtils.createTrustStore(CertUtils.java:62)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.internal.SSLUtils.trustManagers(SSLUtils.java:110)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.internal.SSLUtils.trustManagers(SSLUtils.java:104)
        at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.createHttpClient(HttpClientUtils.java:68)
```

Since I don´t know where to point, could someone give me some guidance?
I don´t know if this a problem with the certificate in the docker, problem with my hazelcast config?

Since I am no expert on this, I am totally lost.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it was a problem with certificate of the docker. Changed it and everything worked as it should

Comment: how did you change your certificate and where did you generate it ?